# Diagonalising the symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to diagonalise the following symmetric matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & -3 \\
      2 & 5 & -4 \\
      -3 & -4 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic equation is:
$\lambda^3 - 14\lambda^2 + 24\lambda + 5 = 0$

The roots that I get are : $11.958, 2.2295, -0.1875$

Now these roots look pretty difficult to work out with. Is there an easier way out?

**Correction**: The question had asked to find a non singular matrix $P$ such that $P^\intercal A P $ is diagonal.

Comment: what is difficult in those roots?

Comment: [does this work ?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-3%2C2%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-5%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C2%2C-3%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)

Comment: if this is a homework, then check your numbers. it is quite unusual to let a student work with decimal approximations in this context.

Comment: @ganeshie8: Could you please explain the method used.

Comment: sure, are you familiar with $A=LU$ factorization? @bhavesh

Comment: @ganeshie8: Yes I know about $LU$ factorization. But what's the intuition behind using that in this case. I have only come across the standard eigen value method for such questions.

Comment: once you have $LU$ form, splitting $U$ into diagonal and uppertriangular is trivial

Comment: Below is the $LU$ factorization for your matrix : $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & -3 \\
      2 & 5 & -4 \\
      -3 & -4 & 8 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0 & 0 \\
      2 & 1 & 0 \\
      -3 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & -3 \\
      0 & 1 & 2 \\
      0 & 0 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$$ Now split the $U$ matrix into a diagonal and uppertriangular

Comment: @ganeshie8: Thanks! I hadn't seen this method earlier.

Comment: @bhavesh, yes: those are the eigenvalues (well, an approximation to...), so if you only need the diagonal form you're done. If you need the diagonalizing matrix P then this can be an ugly problem since the corresponding eigenvectors seem to be extremely horrible. Are you sure the above is the matrix you were given?

Answer (score 1):

Since the diagonalization of a matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix},$$

I don't really see how you could ever hope to avoid the three eigenvalues...